# React-Admin - como que eu passo um id de um ReferenceInput para o filtro de outro ReferenceInput?

Tags: react

Estou tentando passar o exampleId que é o valor do primeiro ReferenceInput no filter do outro ReferenceInput, como que eu faço isso?
O segundo precisa ser carregado dinâmico baseado na seleção do de cima

```
<ArrayInput source="list">
  <SimpleFormIterator>

    <ReferenceInput source="exampleId" reference="Example">
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>

    <ReferenceInput source="exampleIdTwo" reference="ExampleTwo" filter={{ id: exampleId }}>
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>

  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Se eu tento jogar para dentro de um Component para usar com o useState e onChange, acontece isso: **resources.undefined.fields.exampleId**

```
const MyComponent  = () => {
  const [exampleId, setExampleId] = useState(null);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => setExampleId(e.target.value);

  return (
          <SimpleFormIterator>

            <ReferenceInput source="exampleId" reference="Example" onChange={handleOnChange}>
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>

            <ReferenceInput source="exampleIdTwo" reference="ExampleTwo" filter={{ id: exampleId }}>
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>

          </SimpleFormIterator>
  )
}
```

..

```
<ArrayInput source="list">
  <MyComponent />
</ArrayInput>
```

Edit: lib utilizada: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/

Comment: O que é esse `ReferenceInput`? Algum componente de uma biblioteca? O que é o `resources.undefined.fields.exampleId`? Por que isso está errado? Como deveria ser o certo?

Comment: é a biblioteca/lib react-admin
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/
mas eu consegui resolver aqui, vou deixar a resposta abaixo, obrigada!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver.. precisa utilizar o FormDataConsumer

```
<SimpleFormIterator>
    <ReferenceInput source="exampleId" reference="Example">
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>

    <FormDataConsumer >
    {
        ({ getSource, scopedFormData }) => {
        const exampleId = scopedFormData?.exampleId;
        return (
            <ReferenceInput
                source={getSource('exampleIdTwo')}
                reference="ExampleTwo"
                filter={{ id: exampleId }}
            >
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
        )
        }
    }
    </FormDataConsumer>
</SimpleFormIterator>
```